# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am the second developer for this app. I imported the project into xcode 4 and tried to build the app. I am getting 7 "reference from" error. I attached a screenshot. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing frameworks/binaries for FaceBook integration. Do you not have the proper iOS SDK Installed?

Comment: I did install the current SDK.